# react + express + mongoose deploy to heroku not working

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose, mern

I have been trying to deploy my mern (react + express/node.js + passport ) project with heroku.
I have a .env file to define DB_STRING_DEV and SESSION_SECRET.

for some reason when I try to deploy the project, heroku logs shows the following eror message:

"Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string."

and if I go to localhost:5000 
it will only fetch the baseroute get("/") from the backend [request status][1]
but not the routes in react route ( /, /login, /register or other route I defined in react)

Could anyone please kindly advice and help. thank you!!!

the following is the code in my server.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
require("dotenv").config();
}
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8020;
const baseRoute = require("./routes/baseRoute");
const trelloRoute = require("./routes/trelloRoute");
const authRoute = require("./routes/authRoute");
const session = require("express-session");
// get the connection instance
const connection = require("./config/database");



app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use((req, res, next) => {

let start = Date.now(); 

res.once("finish", () => {
  let end = Date.now();
  let time = end - start; 
  console.log(req.method, req.path, res.statusCode, time + "ms");
});

next();
});

app.use("/", baseRoute);
app.use("/auth", authRoute);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
console.log("production!");
app.use(express.static("client/build"));
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../build/index.html"))
});
}


app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server is on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended you don't push `.env` files to Heroku (or github). Instead you should go to your apps settings and add your environment variables in the 'config vars' section.

For routing in Vue I have to set this in my main Express file:

```
// Handle production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    // Static folder
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));

    // Handle SPA
    app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
}
```

Not sure if this applies in React, though I'd imagine it would.

Comment: thank you. Yes I have .gitignore to not push the .env file to Heroku and github. I have also set the config vars in heroku, but it is still not able to deploy so that's why I wonder where I could be wrong ...

Comment: Not sure about React but when I have to push Vue/Express apps to Heroku I have to do some trickery for Vue routes to work. Check my edit.

Comment: @ Daniel_Knights I see  your code now.. it now :) yes I have also done it 
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
console.log("production!");
app.use(express.static("client/build"));
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../build/index.html"))
});
}
but for some reason heruko only can fetch the baseroute but not all other routes from my react...

Comment: Other than maybe your file paths being wrong I'm not sure then

Comment: thank you for the help. In the end i switched the position of the following code and it finally works :)

Answer (score 0):

now I switch the routes after the following code and it finally show my react routes!

```
console.log("production!");
app.use(express.static("client/build"));
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../build/index.html"))
});
}

app.use("/", baseRoute);
app.use("/auth", authRoute);
```